# Preserving CSS comments without modifying the content in YUI compressor

Tags: java, yui

how to compress css file escaping comments in yui compressor.
for e.g i want to preserve comments. As per the yui documentation it says if i put ! inside the comments then it will preserve the comment. But i don't want to alter the css contents. Is there any way to do it in yui compressor. You can suggest any other java based tool which is good for this kind of requirement.